# Help solving a predicate logic question:

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

A(x,y,z): adding vector y to vector x results in vector z

Translate the statement into english: 
∀x.∀y.∀z.A(x,y,z) --> A(y,x,z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this hard for you?   Where are you having trouble?   Take it step by step.

> ∀x.∀y.∀z.A(x,y,z) --> A(y,x,z)

Begin with the quantifiers.   $\forall$ become "any" and the domain is 'vectors', so:

> Any vector x, any vector y, any vector z: A(x,y,z) --> A(y,x,z)

Move to the connectives.   It is a material implication; an "if-then" clause.

> Any vector x, any vector y, any vector z: *if* A(x,y,z) , *then* A(y,x,z) .

Now for the predicates.   Ensure that you substitute the letters in the required order.

> Any vector x, any vector y, any vector z: *if adding vector y to vector x results in any vector z* , then *adding that vector x to that vector y results in that vector z*.

*Finally*, rearrange to more natural language.

> If adding any vector y to any vector x results in a vector z, then too adding vector x to vector y results in vector z.

---

Well, that is as far as you *need* to go; it is what an exam marker would be looking for.   However you *might* want to take the extra step and eliminate the x,y,z symbols.   That is okay too.   Just make sure you preserve the intent and meaning of the statement.   ( On an exam I'd put both down, just to show you understood both the process, and meaning, of the statement. )

> The order of addition of any two vectors is irrelevant, as either way yields the same result.

Which simply means that: "Vector addition is commutative."

Answer (score 1):

For any vectors x,y, and z, if x+y=z then y+x=z.